Requested Grant type authorization code with curl and web
I implemented and it is working correctly in my project the Grant type password to login with email and password
Now, I have activated the Grant type authorization code to login/register with Google using the library https://github.com/thephpleague/oauth2-google
I'm testing with curl and it gives this error
Monolog
[2024-11-13T11:04:48.647981+00:00] AuthService.INFO: Getting client_entity for token request {"client_id":"cdc-client","client_secret":"d9e640ab946ef196003f5972913c570d918bef8e480daa206a10227b87b02cd0"} []
[2024-11-13T11:04:48.658902+00:00] AuthService.INFO: Scopes obtained for user {"user_id":"120","scopes":["view_profile","edit_profile"]} []
[2024-11-13T11:04:48.659074+00:00] AuthService.INFO: Data prepared for token request {"request_data":{"grant_type":"authorization_code","client_id":"cdc-client","client_secret":"d9e640ab946ef196003f5972913c570d918bef8e480daa206a10227b87b02cd0","redirect_uri":"http://localhost:9000/auth/google/callback","code":"4/0AeanS0bLaotKwmbe7AScGHrlnY5zbfSg6QWOFxB4LpOctZ348OgefbxOEuHcZIxiQ2n7RQ","scope":"view_profile edit_profile"},"auth_server_url":"http://localhost:9000/oauth/token"} []
[2024-11-13T11:04:48.838709+00:00] AuthService.ERROR: Error obtaining access token {"exception_message":"Server error: `POST http://localhost:9000/oauth/token` resulted in a `500 Internal Server Error` response:\nThe request is missing a required parameter, includes an invalid parameter value, includes a parameter more than once, o (truncated...)\n","request_data":{"grant_type":"authorization_code","client_id":"cdc-client","client_secret":"d9e640ab946ef196003f5972913c570d918bef8e480daa206a10227b87b02cd0","redirect_uri":"http://localhost:9000/auth/google/callback","code":"4/0AeanS0bLaotKwmbe7AScGHrlnY5zbfSg6QWOFxB4LpOctZ348OgefbxOEuHcZIxiQ2n7RQ","scope":"view_profile edit_profile"},"response_body":"The request is missing a required parameter, includes an invalid parameter value, includes a parameter more than once, or is otherwise malformed."} []

[2024-11-13T11:04:39.389224+00:00] GoogleProviderController.INFO: Redirecting to Google with auth URL {"url":"https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/v2/auth?scope=openid%20email%20profile%20https%3A%2F%2Fwww.googleapis.com%2Fauth%2Fuserinfo.email%20https%3A%2F%2Fwww.googleapis.com%2Fauth%2Fuserinfo.profile&state=3b70e4b1b3afe8daa53ed28ce758d661&response_type=code&redirect_uri=http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A9000%2Fauth%2Fgoogle%2Fcallback&client_id=1092814058687-f20kojo6falrbgam840cliiif2bpb2ao.apps.googleusercontent.com"} []
[2024-11-13T11:04:47.343896+00:00] GoogleProviderController.INFO: Starting Google callback processing {"params":{"state":"3b70e4b1b3afe8daa53ed28ce758d661","code":"4/0AeanS0bLaotKwmbe7AScGHrlnY5zbfSg6QWOFxB4LpOctZ348OgefbxOEuHcZIxiQ2n7RQ","scope":"email profile openid https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.profile https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.email","authuser":"0","prompt":"consent"}} []
[2024-11-13T11:04:47.344119+00:00] GoogleProviderController.INFO: Obtaining access token from Google {"authorization_code":"4/0AeanS0bLaotKwmbe7AScGHrlnY5zbfSg6QWOFxB4LpOctZ348OgefbxOEuHcZIxiQ2n7RQ"} []
[2024-11-13T11:04:47.952762+00:00] GoogleProviderController.INFO: Validating id_token {"id_token":"eyJhbGciOiJSUzI1NiIsImtpZCI6IjFkYzBmMTcyZThkNmVmMzgyZDZkM2EyMzFmNmMxOTdkZDY4Y2U1ZWYiLCJ0eXAiOiJKV1QifQ.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.NIqTtyBzXJrJJPXirCJVUi-Tthu6XE3S31A7mQ6b3wTUIaND3mNJJZ-HLsqbNS6VWoh-sPtIZ67fkBhnV7AcLIvxpNrbNHSTiVCsnzg8FCi9Z2lJW4jAv8VNlAhDkHKutlihCt_v-MQlK63fctvutsj-rZ8M-HpFfm3rasDAC1L1jFEGdbiZ4LVAYDy_wsuPAdhK3slGdZs8KIH2qyn-zzWKjyZl4GYeCYw6_3Z_dq8BCo9wDomuYcVC7IL_YXCtyeMX6bFVHBF9ZkeVCeTUDyzBVN4ZkQ2siEWBpEArhWI5tfykPdwZKHYTxplGeEkWgUr9KuOs_cAMmSna6m12kw"} []
[2024-11-13T11:04:47.953145+00:00] GoogleProviderController.INFO: Starting id_token validation with Google {"id_token":"eyJhbGciOiJSUzI1NiIsImtpZCI6IjFkYzBmMTcyZThkNmVmMzgyZDZkM2EyMzFmNmMxOTdkZDY4Y2U1ZWYiLCJ0eXAiOiJKV1QifQ.eyJpc3MiOiJodHRwczovL2FjY291bnRzLmdvb2dsZS5jb20iLCJhenAiOiIxMDkyODE0MDU4Njg3LWYyMGtvam82ZmFscmJnYW04NDBjbGlpaWYyYnBiMmFvLmFwcHMuZ29vZ2xldXNlcmNvbnRlbnQuY29tIiwiYXVkIjoiMTA5MjgxNDA1ODY4Ny1mMjBrb2pvNmZhbHJiZ2FtODQwY2xpaWlmMmJwYjJhby5hcHBzLmdvb


Curl
curl -X POST http://localhost:9000/oauth/token \
  -H "Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded" \
  -d "grant_type=authorization_code" \
  -d "client_id=cdc-client" \
  -d "client_secret=d9e640ab946ef196003f5972913c570d918bef8e480daa206a10227b87b02cd0" \
  -d "redirect_uri=http://localhost:9000/auth/google/callback" \
  -d "code=4/0AVG7fiT52c1QiaVVJjWdPb7A-izfVsZ4cRfJEaTr8MzY_9AKJXY40XU6A204xOMy2gESvg"

The request is missing a required parameter, includes an invalid parameter value, includes a parameter more than once, or is otherwise malformed.%             ➜  ~

AuthService class method to generate local token
public function obtainAccessTokenByAuthCode(UserEntity $userEntity, string $authCode, Request $request, Response $response): Response
    {
        // Obtenha o client_id e secret do cliente local
        $clientEntity = $this->clientRepository->getFirstClientEntity();
        $this->logger->info("Obtendo client_entity para requisição de token", [
            'client_id' => $clientEntity->getIdentifier(),
            'client_secret' => $clientEntity->getSecret()
        ]);

        // Obtenha os escopos finalizados do ScopeRepository
        $scopes = $this->scopeRepository->getScopesByUserId($userEntity->getIdentifier());
        $scopeIdentifiers = array_map(fn($scope) => $scope->getIdentifier(), $scopes);
        $this->logger->info("Escopos obtidos para o usuário", [
            'user_id' => $userEntity->getIdentifier(),
            'scopes' => $scopeIdentifiers
        ]);

        // Dados para requisição de token
        $requestData = [
            'grant_type' => 'authorization_code',
            'client_id' => $clientEntity->getIdentifier(),
            'client_secret' => $clientEntity->getSecret(),
            'redirect_uri' => $_ENV['GOOGLE_REDIRECT_URI'],
            'code' => $authCode,
            'scope' => implode(' ', $scopeIdentifiers)
        ];

        $this->logger->info("Dados preparados para solicitação de token", [
            'request_data' => $requestData,
            'auth_server_url' => $this->authServerUrl . '/oauth/token'
        ]);

        try {
            $authResponse = $this->httpClient->post($this->authServerUrl . '/oauth/token', [
                'form_params' => $requestData
            ]);

            // Obtenha o corpo completo da resposta para logs
            $responseBody = (string) $authResponse->getBody();
            $this->logger->info("Resposta completa do servidor de autenticação recebida", [
                'status_code' => $authResponse->getStatusCode(),
                'response_body' => json_decode($responseBody, true)
            ]);

            return $response->withHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json')
            ->withStatus($authResponse->getStatusCode())
            ->withBody($authResponse->getBody());

        } catch (\Exception $e) {
            $responseBody = method_exists($e, 'getResponse') ? (string) $e->getResponse()->getBody() : 'No response body';
            $this->logger->error("Erro ao obter token de acesso detalhado", [
                'exception_message' => $e->getMessage(),
                'request_data' => $requestData,
                'response_body' => $responseBody
            ]);

            return $this->jsonResponse($response, [
                'error' => 'token_request_failed',
                'message' => $e->getMessage(),
                'response_body' => $responseBody
            ], 500);
        }

    }

GoogleProviderController class method
public function handleGoogleCallback(Request $request, Response $response): Response
    {
        $params = $request->getQueryParams();

        // Verificar estado para prevenir CSRF
        if (empty($params['state']) || ($params['state'] !== $_SESSION['oauth2state'])) {
            unset($_SESSION['oauth2state']);
            $this->logger->error('Estado inválido na autenticação com o Google', ['state_received' => $params['state'], 'session_state' => $_SESSION['oauth2state']]);
            return $response->withStatus(400)->write('Estado inválido');
        }

        try {
            $this->logger->info('Iniciando processamento do callback do Google', ['params' => $params]);

            // 1. Obter o token de acesso do Google usando o código de autorização
            $this->logger->info('Obtendo token de acesso do Google', ['authorization_code' => $params['code']]);
            $accessToken = $this->googleProvider->getAccessToken('authorization_code', ['code' => $params['code']]);

            $idToken = $accessToken->getValues()['id_token'] ?? null;
            if (!$idToken) {
                $this->logger->error('id_token não encontrado na resposta do Google', ['accessToken' => $accessToken]);
                throw new \Exception("id_token não encontrado.");
            }

            // 2. Validar e extrair o id_token
            $this->logger->info('Validando id_token', ['id_token' => $idToken]);
            $tokenInfo = $this->validateIdToken($idToken);
            if (empty($tokenInfo['email'])) {
                $this->logger->error('E-mail ausente nos dados do Google.', ['tokenInfo' => $tokenInfo]);
                throw new \Exception("E-mail ausente nos dados retornados pelo Google.");
            }

            // 3. Criar ou buscar usuário local
            $googleUserData = [
                'sub' => $tokenInfo['sub'],
                'email' => $tokenInfo['email'],
                'name' => $tokenInfo['name'],
                'picture' => $tokenInfo['picture'],
                'email_verified' => $tokenInfo['email_verified']
            ];

            $this->logger->info('Dados do usuário recebidos do Google', ['googleUserData' => $googleUserData]);

            // Buscar ou criar usuário
            $this->logger->info('Buscando ou criando usuário local', ['googleUserData' => $googleUserData]);
            $userEntity = $this->findOrCreateUser($googleUserData);

            // Gerar token de acesso local
            $this->logger->info('Gerando token de acesso local', ['user_id' => $userEntity->getUserId(), 'code' => $params['code']]);
            $localAccessTokenResponse = $this->authService->obtainAccessTokenByAuthCode($userEntity, $params['code'], $request, $response);

            // Decodificar a resposta para verificar o token gerado
            $tokenData = json_decode((string) $localAccessTokenResponse->getBody(), true);
            if (!isset($tokenData['access_token'])) {
                $this->logger->error("Falha ao gerar token de acesso local após o login com o Google", ['localAccessTokenResponse' => $localAccessTokenResponse]);
                $response->getBody()->write('Erro interno de autenticação');
                return $response->withStatus(500);
            }

            $this->logger->info('Token de acesso local gerado com sucesso', ['tokenData' => $tokenData]);

            // Configurar o cookie com o token de acesso
            setcookie('access_token', $tokenData['access_token'], [
                'expires' => time() + 3600,
                'path' => '/',
                'secure' => false,
                'httponly' => true,
                'samesite' => 'Strict'
            ]);

            // Redirecionar de acordo com o papel do usuário
            $username = $userEntity->getUsername();
            $redirectUrl = match ($userEntity->getRole()) {
                'admin' => '/admin/',
                'moderator' => '/moderator/',
                'user' => '/u/@' . $username,
                'developer' => '/developer/',
                default => '/u/@' . $username,
                };

                $this->logger->info('Usuário autenticado com sucesso e redirecionado', [
                    'user_id' => $userEntity->getUserId(),
                    'redirect_url' => $redirectUrl
                ]);

                return $response->withHeader('Location', $redirectUrl)->withStatus(302);

            } catch (\Exception $e) {
                $this->logger->error('Erro ao processar callback do Google: ' . $e->getMessage(), ['exception' => $e]);
                return $response->getBody()->write('Erro durante a autenticação com o Google.');
                return $response->withStatus(500);
            }
        }

Routes
$app->get('/auth/google', GoogleProviderController::class . ':redirectToGoogle');
$app->get('/auth/google/callback', GoogleProviderController::class . ':handleGoogleCallback');


$app->post('/oauth/token', function (Request $request, Response $response) use ($server) {
        try {
            return $server->respondToAccessTokenRequest($request, $response);
        } catch (OAuthServerException $exception) {
            return $exception->generateHttpResponse($response);
        } catch (\Exception $exception) {
            // Correção para criação do Stream com recurso
            $body = new Stream(fopen('php://temp', 'r+'));
            $body->write($exception->getMessage());
            return $response->withStatus(500)->withBody($body);
        }
    });

My problem is basically this, I receive the information from Google and it is valid, however, when switching to a local token it does not generate

What does "when switching to a local token" actually mean here?

I receive a code from Google and try to generate a local token

I can't even tell right now, if that "The request is missing a required parameter, includes an invalid parameter value, [or or or]" stuff is a response generated by your system, or a response coming directly from the Google API.

"[2024-11-13T11:04:48.838709+00:00] AuthService.ERROR: Error obtaining access token {"exception_message":"Server error: POST http://localhost:9000/oauth/token resulted in a 500 Internal Server Error ..." - please try and narrow down, which part of your code actually caused this entry. There's multiple places in your shown code where you deliberately respond with a 500 status code.

If you are trying to log in via Google, use the OAuth CLIENT package. You appear to have installed the OAuth2 SERVER. If indeed you do have your own oauth2, bear in mind this has nothing to do with googles stuff, the token endpoint is with google, all you should be doing is associating the token google gives you to your new or existing user
